# How to scroll content horizontally without scroll bar and just by using CSS

Tags: jquery, css

Same as this site: https://www.tumblr.com/explore/text
You can see, when we drag the hashtags in each post in the above site, they are automatically pulled horizontally and there is not any scrollbars. But this effect is created by javascript combined with css.

Now I don't know if we can do the same effect with just pure css or not. Please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not possible with pure css.

Comment: I must be missing something...you are saying that that sight can scroll horizontally? Horizontally as in left to right and vice versa, correct?

Comment: @zer00ne that's right. You should see the site above to make it more clear

Comment: I did...The only thing I see that scrolls horizontally is a slideshow, is that what you meant?

Comment: @zer00ne No zer. It's not a slideshow. It's the draggable hashtags which you can drag to the left and right.

Comment: This can't be done with pure css. Use jquery instead. there's a bunch of jquery plugin that scrolls your list horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think what you are after is something like the following

http://jsfiddle.net/dd9xqzp2/

You will need to tinker around with it a bit.

Basically you are hiding the scrollbars. Its a bit clunky but thats what you'd expect I guess without the jquery smoothness.

Html

```
<div class="viewport-clip">
  <div class="viewport">
    <div class="horizontal">
      <div class="item">#test</div>
      <div class="item">#test1</div>
      <div class="item">#test2</div>
      <div class="item">#test3</div>
      <div class="item">#test4</div>
      <div class="item">#test5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
*/

.viewport-clip {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.viewport {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px; /* Note the excessive extra height to keep h-scrollbar at bay */
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.horizontal {
  width: 330px;
  height: 30px;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  background: white;
  color:#888;
  padding-right: 5px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I mean we would not use any javascript here @Ace

Comment: They are not the same @Ace. Do you know slick slider carousel? These hashtags work like that. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Ok, I think what you are after is more like what I'm putting in my answer now.